# set values to form control without NgModel, Reactive Forms?

Tags: angular

i use angular 9

i have reactive form with 3 textboxes and one selection / options ( this is to load country names ). Other textboxes are for first, middle and last name entry. 
These are in a modal popup

i have the following markup for text box:

```
   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first-name">Contact First Name</label>
            <input type="text"  formControlName="first"  class="form-control" id="first-name" placeholder="Bill" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.first.errors }" >
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.first.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.first.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
            </div>          
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last-name">Contact Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="last" class="form-control" id="last-name" placeholder="Clinton" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.last.errors }" >
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.last.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.last.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
            </div>          
          </div>
```

markup for the select/options are like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="country">Country</label>             
              <select class="form-control" id="country" formControlName="country"  (change)="changeCountry($event)"  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.country.errors }" >
                <option value="">Choose your country</option>
                <option *ngFor="let c of countryList" value="{{c.Code}}">{{c.Name}}</option>       
              </select>

              <!-- <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && country.errors.required">
                <sup>*</sup>Please enter your city name
              </div> -->

              <div *ngIf="submitted && f.country.errors?.required" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.country.errors?.required">Select country</div>
              </div>

</div>
```

i have the following ts code of the component to asign values to the form fields

```
  this.newClientForm.setValue(
      {'company':  companyName, 
      'street' : addressL1,
      'city' : city,
      'postal' : zip,
      'state' : state,
      'first' : firstName,
      'last' : lastName,
      'email' : email,
      'country' : countryCode //this has value of option
    });
```

but all fields gets assigns except country which is a select / options, when i assign countryCode value to country field as above, it looses the list of country it had at teh initial load.

then i load information on to a Grid which is on the same component, i have placed a button i can get the records that was selected. But how do i 
send the row data to select/options and other textboxes at once. as you can see i dont use ngNodel so i need to solutios without ngModel?

Comment: I don't get your question. Data needs to come from *what*? *Where* does it need to go? *When*?

Comment: @KurtHamilton data initially gets loaded on to a Grid then i hit the edit button on it and the record should load on to that form

Comment: Can you provide a live example. This is all very abstract and non-specific at the moment

Comment: @KurtHamilton this code was extracted.... i'm only having the issue with the selection options when i assign values using 
  this.newClientForm.setValue(
      {'company':  companyName, 
      'street' : addressL1,
      'city' : city,
      'postal' : zip,
      'state' : state,
      'first' : firstName,
      'last' : lastName,
      'email' : email,
      'country' : [countrList[1]]
    });
but it wont assign the select options

Comment: @KurtHamilton let me udpate the post

Comment: @KurtHamilton i have updated the post

Comment: It works when I mock it up in stackblitz. This is why we need to see **all relevant** code. Otherwise everyone's guessing at what your problem *might* be.

Comment: Can you show your `countryList` code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this for your option

```
this.newClientForm.controls['country'].setValue(countryCode , {onlySelf: true});
```

Comment: yea, but is there a way to set values to all control from a single code block?

Comment: CustomermanagerComponent.html:59 ERROR Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'country', this is the error it provides

Comment: Can you post the code from your ts file where you create the form?Are you using FormBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Tzimpo answer to set the value of select.

Also change html:

```
<select class="form-control" id="country" formControlName="country"  (change)="changeCountry($event)"  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.country.errors }" >
                <option value="">Choose your country</option>
                <option *ngFor="let c of countryList" [value]="c.Code">{{c.Name}}</option>       
              </select>
```